# USB devices not detected

Tags: usb, updates, devices, lsusb

None of them seem to show up in `lsusb`. Neither my mouse nor any USB drives.

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But dmesg seems to detect them:
http://pastebin.com/zeepayd5

I was recommended to just reinstall Ubuntu, and USB devices worked after that, but they stopped working after I updated. I think I started having this problem after updating around last night, so all I can think of is that it's something to do with the update.

Comment: Could you update to the latest stable mainline kernel and try again? Download linux-headers-3.19.3-031903-generic, linux-headers-3.19.3-031903 and linux-image-3.19.3-031903-generic from [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19.3-vivid/) (for the correct architecture: if you've installed 64 bit Ubuntu, get the files ending in amd64.deb, otherwise, get the files ending in i386.deb). Then, in the terminal, install the kernel with `sudo dpkg -i <the three files you downloaded>`.

Comment: got something about "possibly missing firmware"
>W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8107e-2.fw for module r8169
>W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8107e-1.fw for module r8169
>W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168h-2.fw for module r8169
>W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168h-1.fw for module r8169

And now I need to restart it seems

Comment: Try to install the linux-firmware package with `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware`, and if that does not work, try installing the linux-firmware-nonfree package too

Comment: Downloading the new kernel seems to have worked. And it seems I already have the stuff in linux-firmware.

Answer (score 1):

You might have been affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1313279). Updating to a newer kernel may solve your issue.

1. Find your Ubuntu installation's architecture.
   Run `uname -m`. If it returns `i386` or `i686`, then it's i386 (32-bit); if it returns `x86_64` or `amd64`, then it's amd64 (64-bit).
2. Download the latest mainline stable kernel from [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19.3-vivid/).
   In this case, you should download the following:

   ```
   linux-headers-3.19.3-031903-generic_3.19.3-031903.201503261036_ARCH.deb
   linux-headers-3.19.3-031903_3.19.3-031903.201503261036_all.deb
   linux-image-3.19.3-031903-generic_3.19.3-031903.201503261036_ARCH.deb
   ```

   Replace `ARCH` with the architecture found above (`i386` or `amd64`)
3. Install the packages with `sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.19.3-031903-generic_3.19.3-031903.201503261036_ARCH.deb linux-headers-3.19.3-031903_3.19.3-031903.201503261036_all.deb linux-image-3.19.3-031903-generic_3.19.3-031903.201503261036_ARCH.deb`, again replacing `ARCH` with your kernel architecture
4. Reboot.

Answer (score -3):

You better reinstall to fix it easy, or just try installing a device manager from software center and there you will find the usb devices connected. Then click on one, and format it. Then you can simply start using it as usual.I've done it with the usb 3.0 pendrive I had. And now it works perfect.

Comment: He had already mentioned that it worked on a clean install of Ubuntu, but it broke after updating.

Comment: The problem is with my software rather than any specific usb device.  And I already did reinstall, but everything stopped working again after an update.  System profiler doesn't detect any USB devices either.

Comment: @zhongfu Thats why I told him to reinstall the upgrade or ubuntu to fix it. Please don't downvote

Comment: The problem is that he **has already reinstalled Ubuntu**, i.e. done what you suggested for him to do.

Comment: @zhongfu So if its not working. I don't know how to fix it. Just try reinstall drivers. or don't upgrade again.  I prefer to download iso and install it